# Run SQL command with "Add To Cart" link in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array that puts products into a table (and is searchable), I want to be able to add items to a cart table in the database. More specifically I want to run a SQL command through the "add to cart" link. This is how it's currently set up. I read around the onClick JS could work, but I couldn't find a clear cut way to implement it.

```
<?php 

            $table="SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY ProductID ASC"; 
            $sq=mysqli_query($db,$table); 
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sq) == 0){


            echo "Search For a Product";
                ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }else{
            while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($sq)) { 
                  $pname = $row2['ProductName'];
                  $pdesc = $row2['ProductDescription'];
                  $pprice = $row2['ProductPrice'];
                  $pinv = $row2['ProductInventory'];
                  $pid = $row2['ProductID'];
        ?> 
                <tr> 
                    <td><?php echo $row2['ProductName'] ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row2['ProductDescription'] ?></td>
                    <td>$<?php echo $row2['ProductPrice'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row2['ProductInventory'] ?></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="<?php echo $pid ?>" value="Add To Cart"></td>                
                </tr> 
        <?php 

            }
         }  
        ?>
```

Comment: So the question is? Nothing above will insert into the db - you have only included code that fetches data.

Comment: As of now yes, I've been trying to post the echo into a form and call it from a separate php page that inserts the data and redirects back to product page but that obviously hasn't worked.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to turn the "add to cart" link into a SQL insert command

Answer (score 0):

Rather than post to a separate page you could utilise ajax and send the requests to the same page ( or different ) so it makes it a better experience for your users. The code below is quickly cobbled together to give an idea as to how you could achieve the desired goal.

You would probably want to include a quantity for each item which would get sent along with the request - some simple additions to the `params` object of the click handling function.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( !empty( $_POST['action'] ) ){
            switch( $_POST['action'] ){
                case 'add':
                    $sql='insert into `table` (f1,f2,f3) values (?,?,?)'; /*etc*/
                break;
                case 'delete':
                    $sql='delete from `table` where `id`=?';
                break;
                case 'update':
                    $sql='update `table` set f1=? where `id`=?';
                break;
                case 'checkout':
                    /* other stuff, probably best handled with another page */
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            the products would be generated by a db call and rendered rather than statically typed as here
        -->
        <form>
            <!-- product #1 -->
            <div>
                <!-- /* product details */ -->
                <a href='#' class='bttn-add' id='product-1'>Add to cart</a>
            </div>

            <!-- product #2 -->
            <div>
                <!-- /* product details */ -->
                <a href='#' class='bttn-add' id='product-2'>Add to cart</a>
            </div>


            <!-- product #3 -->
            <div>
                <!-- /* product details */ -->
                <a href='#' class='bttn-add' id='product-3'>Add to cart</a>
            </div>
        </form>


        <script>

            function evtClickHandler(e){
                ajax.call( this, 'post',location.href,{ action:'add',id:this.id },evtCallback,{/* options */});
            }
            function evtCallback(response){
                alert(r); /* process the response accordingly to manipulate the DOM etc */
            }

            /* utility function for making ajax requests */
            function ajax( method, url, params, callback, options ){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )callback.call( this, xhr.response, options, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var async=params.hasOwnProperty('async') ? params.async : true;
                var query=[];

                for( var n in params )query.push( n+'='+params[n] );

                switch( method.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': query=query.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': url+='?'+query.join('&'); query=null; break;
                }

                xhr.open( method.toUpperCase(), url, async );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( query );
            }



            /* Assign event listeners to the various buttons/anchors on the html page rather than inline handlers */
            var col=document.querySelectorAll('a.bttn-add');
            if( col ){
                for( var n in col ){
                    if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
                        col[ n ].addEventListener('click',evtClickHandler.bind( col[n] ),false);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is intended to give guidance only rather than being a definitive solution - it remains untested so there might be little mistooks lurking in there due to the speed of writing etc but I hope it helps a little

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look into this